# App for playing music in a continuous overlapping way

Tags: music, android-app, app

I'm looking for an app that could play music is such a way that it sounds like a single mix. It should be able to skip for example the initial 30 seconds of each song and also the endings and play them continuously.

I don't mind other features like random order etc. but the overlapping mode and skipping x seconds are the most important ones.